# pFsense : A rule apply on user account

Tags: openvpn, pfsense, rules

I have a pFsense user account 'foo.extern'. This account can log to the server with OpenVPN. It works fine.

Now i want to make a firewall rule to allow this account only access to the IP adresse 192.168.56.20.

When i try the following parameters. i got the error message : **foo.extern is not a valid source IP address or alias.**

Here the rule setup

```
- Action to "Pass."
- Interface to OpenVPN interface.
- Address Family to "IPv4."
- Protocol to "Any" 
- Source section : Type to "Single host or alias" and IP address to 'foo.external'.
- Destination section : Type to "Single host or alias" and IP address to 192.168.56.20.
```

So how to specify a rule by applied on a account name over IP adress.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> So how to specify a rule by applied on a account name over IP adress.

You *can't*.

The firewall decides based on the IP header. There's no field for username in the IP header.

The [OpenVPN documentation](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/configuring-client-specific-rules-and-access-policies/) shows how to push different routes for different clients based on CN.

Note that running openvpn on pfsense tends to be somewhat less flexible than running it standalone, as it attempts to hide configuration files, and only give you access to the web ui.